# replace DIV content in HTML on Radio click

Tags: javascript, html, swap

I have an HTML where we display 3 SELECT drop downs and 1 checkbox.
The requirement is just to swap the first two select drop downs based on a radio click.

Initially when the page loads (View B within a A is selected)
When you select "View A within a B" ,the DIV contents should swap and UI elements should stay as is. i.e; Select Option C and Select Option D position should not change.
With the following code, all SELECT are getting re-arranged.

```
var target1 = document.querySelector( '.swap-row > :first-child' );
var target2 = document.querySelector( '.swap-row > :nth-child(2)' );
var parent = target1.parentNode;
parent.insertBefore( target1, null );
parent.insertBefore( target2, parent.firstChild );
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m66dw.png)

Comment: Can you please provide your HTML and CSS, ideally in a jsFiddle?

Comment: the HTML select drop downs are rendered dynamically. Its not a static one.

Comment: If it is rendered dynamically, can you provide a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Like a static snapshot of a dynamically rendered page. (and keep in mind that you can -- and are encouraged to -- directly embed html/css/js examples into your posts nowadays, so there's no need for a jsfiddle)

Comment: it is difficult to create a static snapshot, all I can tell is, how many how many select drop downs/how many radio buttons to be rendered and what they are , are given by a json.